# How to recruit sailors?

Tags: port-royale-3

Maybe I missed that part of the tutorial but I cannot find the place where I can hire sailors for my convoy. Please, can you indicate me how to do it?

Comment: To be fair, the tutorials are pretty shabby

Answer (score 1):

You can hire Sailors in the dock of each port.